# How to generate a formula of a graph with three key points

Tags: interpolation

I have three key points on a graph. How do I find out what the formula for this graph would be?
The points are:
(3,0) (5,2) (7,6).
It is known that the graph will be a quadratic.
Thanks

Comment: "quadratic" means parabola?

Comment: Try `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{3, 0}, {5, 2}, {7, 6}}, x]` or `LinearAlgebra\`VandermondeSolve[{3, 5, 7}, {0, 2, 6}, Transpose -> True].x^Range[0, 2]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `Fit`:

```
Fit[{{3, 0} , {5, 2}, {7, 6}}, {1, x, x^2}, x]
```

The graph can be generated by:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Fit[{{3, 0} , {5, 2}, {7, 6}}, {1, x, x^2}, x], {x, 2, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your case, another approach is to solve the equations generated by the given points:

```
exp = a x^2 + b x + c ;
eqn = Table[((exp == y ) /. {x -> i[[1]], y -> i[[2]]}), 
            {i, {{3, 0} , {5, 2}, {7, 6}}}];
sol = Solve[eqn, {a, b, c}]
Plot[exp /. sol, {x, 2, 8}]
```

Of course, this solution will not work if the number of points increases and some of these points are not located on the curve.