# To obtain an equation for a given curve

Tags: fitting

I have obtained the graph,

[image]

I would like to know its equation. The graph seems to be a hyperbolic spiral which, its equation reads, $r = a/\theta$. I read [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/how-to-generate-a-formula-of-a-graph-with-three-key-points/13242#13242) and [also](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37141/getting-an-equation-of-particular-curve), but these are concerning the Cartesian coordinate system. How could one implement these methods for my case, i. e. the polar coordinate system?

#### Edit (1)

Here is the code:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {Im[(4.85263 + I 1.15883) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + 
      (-2.21527 + I 2.36121) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + 
      (-2.35438 + I 1.36651) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + 
      (0.717016 - I 0.836553) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]], 
   Im[(4.85263 + I 1.15883) (-0.455 + I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + 
      (-2.21527 + I 2.36121) (0.455 + I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + 
      (-2.35438 + I 1.36651) (0.455 - I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + 
      (0.717016 - I 0.836553) (-0.455 - I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]]}, 
  {t, 0, 4.47}]
```

#### Edit (2)

Actually, by the above approach, I would like to obtain an explicit equation from some given parametric equations. I do not know whether there exist other approaches or not.

Comment: Transform the data to polar coordinates and do the fit.

Comment: Is there a simpler method? Because, this graph has been obtained by some parametric plot, in other words, I do not have the data explicitly.

Comment: You can use Cases to get Line or Points coordinates.

Comment: Do you only have the plot or also the generating code? Please add as much info as possible.

Comment: @YvesKlett I had two functions of t, i. e. a(t) and b(t), I parametrically plotted b versus a, i. e. the above graph. Now, I would like to find the equation b(a). (b as a function of a)

Comment: are trying to get best a?

Comment: @Algohi No. Imagine two dimensional motion, one of them x(t) and, the other y(t). I plotted y versus x above. Now, I am searching for y(x).

Comment: @Algohi and also, I do not know exactly whether the equation should be hyperbolic spiral or not; merely I guess.

Comment: @ToBe are you looking for polar function or Cartesian function? I don't think for such case you can get Cartesian function.

Comment: post the functions

Comment: @Algohi Actually, I did not understand your sentence. Let me rephrase my problem. I have two functions of t, say x(t) and y(t). I plotted parametrically y versus x. The above plot is the result. Because of its behavior, I think, a polar equation is more appropriate to describe it; and I guess, it could be something like hyperbolic spiral.

Comment: Or post the data.

Comment: @george2079 I added the code.

Comment: @Algohi I added the code.

Comment: Pretty sure it's *not* a hyperbolic spiral: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SIjME.png

Answer (score 7):

You can try to implicitize, sort of. I do this step by step so we can see what substitutions are needed.

```
exprs = 
 ExpToTrig[
  Expand[Simplify[
    Chop[ComplexExpand[{Im[(4.85263 + 
            I 1.15883) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.21527 + 
            I 2.36121) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.35438 + 
            I 1.36651) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + (0.717016 - 
            I 0.836553) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]], 
       Im[(4.85263 + I 1.15883) (-0.455 + 
            I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.21527 + 
            I 2.36121) (0.455 + 
            I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.35438 + 
            I 1.36651) (0.455 - 
            I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + (0.717016 - 
            I 0.836553) (-0.455 - 
            I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]]}]]]]]

(* Out[115]= {0.322277 Cos[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] - Sinh[0.455 t]) + 
  4.135614 Sin[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] - Sinh[0.455 t]) + 
  3.72772 Cos[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] + Sinh[0.455 t]) + 
  0.13911 Sin[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] + Sinh[0.455 t]), 
 4.398403751 Cos[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] - Sinh[0.455 t]) - 
  2.235886793 Sin[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] - Sinh[0.455 t]) + 
  1.84899449 Cos[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] + Sinh[0.455 t]) - 
  4.03346923 Sin[1.099 t] (Cosh[0.455 t] + Sinh[0.455 t])} *)
```

We will "algebraicize" by substituting for the trigs and hyperbolics, and adding suitable defining relations. I am making an intentional error here in that I use `r*cos` for `x`, and similar for `y`, when really `cos` stands for `Cos[1.099 t]` rather than `Cos[t]`. One can do this correctly but the later computations might get bogged down.

```
e2 = exprs /. {Sinh[0.455` t] -> sinh, Cosh[0.455` t] -> cosh, 
    Sin[1.099` t] -> sin, Cos[1.099` t] -> cos};
e3 = Join[
  Expand[Numerator[Together[r*{cos, sin} - e2]]], {cos^2 + sin^2 - 1, 
   cosh^2 - sinh^2 - 1}]

(* Out[140]= {-4.049997 cos cosh + cos r - 4.274724 cosh sin - 
  3.405443 cos sinh + 3.996504 sin sinh, -6.247398241 cos cosh + 
  6.269356023 cosh sin + r sin + 2.549409261 cos sinh + 
  1.797582437 sin sinh, -1 + cos^2 + sin^2, -1 + cosh^2 - sinh^2} *)
```

Now form a Groebner basis and get the first element in terms of `r` and a hyperbolic.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[Rationalize[e3, 0], {cos, sin, cosh, sinh, r}];
```

I'm not showing the longish polynomial in `r` and `sinh` but indeed there is one at the beginning of the basis. Get explicit solutions so we can use `PolarPlot`.

```
solns = Solve[gb[[1]] == 0, r];

PolarPlot[(r /. solns[[2]]) /. sinh -> Sinh[.455*t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

I don't know if this really gives a useful result but I guess it might give ideas for how one could proceed.

Comment: Cute. +1 IMO, `r*cos` for `x` is not an error, if `θ = 1.099 t` and we think of `1.099` as an angular velocity.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks, that's a good way to view it (of course I'm biased, but still).

Answer (score 6):

The coordinates of the parametric curve consist of the solution of a fourth-order linear differential equation and its derivative.  This is clear by inspection.

First, we need the x coordinate in a form that can be differentiated:

```
xOP = Im[(4.85263 + I 1.15883) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.21527 +
        I 2.36121) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.35438 + 
       I 1.36651) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + (0.717016 - 
       I 0.836553) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]];
solOP = xOP // ComplexExpand
(*
  -0.836553 E^(0. - 0.455 t) Cos[0. - 1.099 t] + 
   1.36651  E^(0. + 0.455 t) Cos[0. - 1.099 t] + 
   1.15883  E^(0. - 0.455 t) Cos[0. + 1.099 t] + 
   2.36121  E^(0. + 0.455 t) Cos[0. + 1.099 t] + 
   0.717016 E^(0. - 0.455 t) Sin[0. - 1.099 t] - 
   2.35438  E^(0. + 0.455 t) Sin[0. - 1.099 t] + 
   4.85263  E^(0. - 0.455 t) Sin[0. + 1.099 t] - 
   2.21527  E^(0. + 0.455 t) Sin[0. + 1.099 t]
*)
```

We can see the characteristic values from the coefficients in the exponents. We can grab these with [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html).  They are the roots of the characteristic equation:

```
exponents = Cases[xOP, Exp[x_] :> x/t, Infinity]
(*
  {-0.455 - 1.099 I, -0.455 + 1.099 I, 0.455 - 1.099 I, 0.455 + 1.099 I}
*)

chareqn0 = Fold[(m - #2) #1 &, 1, exponents] // Expand // Chop
(*
   2.00173 + 2.00155 m^2 + m^4
*)
```

You know, those coefficients are close to `2`, and the problem had the exponents to only three digits.  I'll bet they're rounded off.  Let's see:

```
chareqn = Fold[(m - #2) #1 &, 1, SetPrecision[exponents, 3]] == 0 //
  Expand // Rationalize[#, 0] &
(*
  2 + 2 m^2 + m^4 == 0
*)
```

We can compare numerically and see it's very close.

```
NSolve[chareqn, m]
(*
  {{m -> -0.45509 - 1.09868 I}, {m -> -0.45509 + 1.09868 I},
   {m ->  0.45509 - 1.09868 I}, {m ->  0.45509 + 1.09868 I}}
*)
```

For simplicity, let's proceed with the integer coefficients.  We can form the ODE in the same way as the characteristic equation and solve it for the general solution:

```
ode = Fold[(D[#1, t] - #2 #1) &, u[t], SetPrecision[exponents, 3]] == 0 //
   Expand // Rationalize[#, 0] &
(*
  2 u[t] + 2 u''[t] + u''''[t] == 0
*)

solGEN = First@DSolve[ode, u[t], t]
(*
  {u[t] ->
     E^(-2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  C[2] Cos[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
     E^( 2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  C[3] Cos[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
     E^( 2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  C[1] Sin[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
     E^(-2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  C[4] Sin[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]]}
*)
```

Now we can use the particular solution from the OP's parametrization to solve for the coefficient `C[1]` etc.

```
NestList[D[#, t] &, (u[t] /. solGEN) == solOP, 3] /. t -> 0;
Solve[%, Array[C, 4]]
sol0 = u[t] /. solGEN /. First[%]
(*
  {{C[1] -> 0.136723, C[2] -> 0.319596, C[3] -> 3.7304, C[4] -> 4.13673}}    

  0.319596 E^(-2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  Cos[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
  3.7304   E^( 2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  Cos[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
  4.13673  E^(-2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  Sin[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]] + 
  0.136723 E^( 2^(1/4) t Sin[π/8])  Sin[2^(1/4) t Cos[π/8]]
*)
```

Plot the solution:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sol0, D[sol2, t]}], {t, 0, 4.47}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure just what form is desired, polar or cartesian.  It seems to me that recognizing where the plot is from is a good step toward knowing how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

This maybe not an efficient way of doing this problem, but here is my approach:

First you need to convert the parametric data into polar data. my way of doing this is as follows ( I don't know any better way to convert data from {x,y} to {t,r}):

```
    data = Table[{Im[(4.85263 + 
             I 1.15883) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.21527 + 
             I 2.36121) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.35438 + 
             I 1.36651) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + (0.717016 - 
             I 0.836553) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]], 
        Im[(4.85263 + I 1.15883) (-0.455 + 
             I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.21527 + 
             I 2.36121) (0.455 + 
             I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 + I 1.099) t] + (-2.35438 + 
             I 1.36651) (0.455 - 
             I 1.099) Exp[(0.455 - I 1.099) t] + (0.717016 - 
             I 0.836553) (-0.455 - 
             I 1.099) Exp[(-0.455 - I 1.099) t]]}, {t, 0, 4.47, .1}];
    dataparametric = Reverse@data;
angl0 = VectorAngle[{1, 0}, dataparametric[[1]]];
angles = VectorAngle[dataparametric[[#]], dataparametric[[# + 1]]] & /@
    Range[1, Length@dataparametric - 1];
polarangles = 
  Join[{angl0}, 
   Total[angles[[;; #]]] & /@ Range[1, Length@dataparametric - 1] + 
    angl0];
r = Norm /@ dataparametric;
polardata = Transpose[{polarangles, r}];
```

then you can do normal fitting as follows:

```
func = a/t /. FindFit[polardata, a/t, a, t];
(*47.9031/t*)
```

all of this looks like follows:

```
p1 = ListPlot[dataparametric, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]];
p2 = Show[
   ListPlot[dataparametric, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}], 
   Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, #2 {Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}}] & @@@ polardata, 
    AspectRatio -> 1]];
p3 = PolarPlot[func, {t, 1.5, 2.2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]];
Show[p3, p1, p2]
```

[image]